# When to delete/dereference in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, dereference

```
myObj* var = new myObj;
var = other1;
```

don't need it anymore

```
delete var;
var = new myObj;
var = other2;
```

why can't just dereference instead of deleting and allocating again?

```
var->other2;
```

Comment: *why can't just dereference instead of deleting and allocating again?* i keep reading that trying to make sense of it, but what?

Comment: @thang setting the value of the pointer to something else.

Comment: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/dereference *to access the thing to which the pointer points.*?  that's the dereference you mean to use?

Comment: You seem to have received some misguided guidance. Don't delete something if you still want to use it. But don't use `new` or `delete` at all until you're sure you know what you're doing (at which point you'll know to generally avoid them).

Answer (score 2):

Dereference does not mean delete: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dereference

I suggest you go through some tutorials on C++, as you seem to have a misunderstanding of what a lot of the vocabulary actually means.

Remember to use google.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is silly, absolutely no offence intended. In other words, you have an underlying confusion here, that cannot be addressed by a simple answer to an inquiry.

I'd strongly recommend you read introductory material to C or C++. The web is full to the brim with excellent lectures, and free e-books. You won't regret it!

Google around :) and maybe, you'll come back to answer your own question in a few days.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Others have commented on your confusion about terminology. I'll comment on your code.

When you do:

```
myObj* var = new myObj;
var = other1;
```

you're creating a [memory leak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak). `new myObj` allocated memory for a structure, and set `var` to point there. When you then reassign `var`, you no longer have a variable pointing to the structure that was allocated. C++ does not have automatic garbage collection, so this memory is no longer accessible, but you also don't have a variable that you can use with `delete` to reclaim it.

`var = other1` reassigns the pointer, it does *not* copy the contents; if you want to copy structures, you must write:

```
*var = *other1;
```

When you then do:

```
delete var;
```

you're not deleting the original structure, you're deleting whatever `other` pointed to. This is only valid if that structure was created using `new`.

You definitely need to go back and review all your instructional material on pointers in C++.